# React – can't filter array properly

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to add filter functionality to my project. From a list of entries with different languages, an array of all languages is created. The user should be able to click a language and have React filter to only show entries with that language. However, I can't seem to update the `entries` state properly when running the `filterIt` function. If I console.log entries after running `setEntries(filtered)`, the result is the same.

```
const Archive = () => {
  const [entries, setEntries] = useState([]);
  let dreamFilter = [];

  //get all entries from firestore
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("entries")
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        const newEntries = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
          id: doc.id,
          ...doc.data(),
        }));
        setEntries(newEntries);
      });
    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, []);

  //after entries are loaded, create filter of all languages for 'dream'
  if (entries.length > 0) {
    const categoryMap = Object.values(entries)
      .reduce(
        (concatedArr, item) => concatedArr.concat(Object.entries(item)),
        []
      )
      .reduce((result, [category, values]) => {
        result[category] = result[category] || [];
        result[category] = result[category].concat(values);
        return result;
      }, {});

      dreamFilter = categoryMap.dream.filter(
        (item, pos) => categoryMap.dream.indexOf(item) === pos
      );
  }

  function filterIt(value) {
    const filtered = entries.filter(entry => ({
      ...entry,
      filtered: entry.dream.includes(value)
    }));
    console.log("filtered results = " + JSON.stringify(filtered));
    setEntries(filtered);
    return filtered;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Navigation />
      <ul>
        {dreamFilter.map((language, i) => (
          <li key={i}>
            <a href="/" onClick={(value) => { filterIt(value); value.preventDefault(); }}>{language}</a>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <ArchiveContainer>
        {entries.map((entry) => (
          <div key={entry.id}>
            <a href={"/entry/" + entry.id}>
              <h5>{entry.id}</h5>
              <p>{entry.dream}</p>
            </a>
          </div>
        ))}
      </ArchiveContainer>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Filter method should return either true or false. Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
If you want to convert one array to an array of another object, then use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

You need to modify filter method to be like this:

```
const filtered = entries.filter(entry => entry.dream.includes(value));
```

Answer (score 0):

In functional component you can't update states directly.
assuming here you are trying to add **filtered: true/false** also in **entries** array.
*array.filter* is for adding or removing the object from array by returning true/false.

```
function filterIt(value) {
 setEntries(entryList => entryList.map(item => ({
   ...item,
   filtered: item.dream.includes(value)
 })));
}
```